# React for loop create infinite call

Tags: reactjs

I'm currently encountering a problem when i'm calling a for loop in a functional/class component in React. For exemple if I want to create a simple function to render multiple td tr in a table React is going to infinite call the function.

```
class ReserveView extends Component {
  createTable() {
    const table = []

    for (let i = 0; i < 3; i + 1) {
      const children = []
      for (let j = 0; j < 5; j + 1) {
        children.push(<td>{`Column ${j + 1}`}</td>)
      }
      table.push(<tr>{children}</tr>)
    }
    return table
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <table>
          {this.createTable()}
        </table>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

If i console.log(j) the console will output
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLdeU.png)

I'm using React for a year now and it's the first time I'm having this issue. Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 3):

Oh yeah, your problem lies in the fact that you never increase the `i` and `j` loop variant.

you need to do `i++` and `j++` instead of `j + 1` :)

Comment: I've just tried and it works !! thanks a lot :). I guess i'll have to change my linter !

Answer (score 2):

Change your `+1`s to `++`

```
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  const children = []
  for (let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
    children.push(<td>{`Column ${j + 1}`}</td>)
  }
  table.push(<tr>{children}</tr>)
}
return table
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer has been posted above. Just a note that you may try ES6 map() function. It would be very useful when you are coding with React.

```
  createTable2() {
    const rows = Array(3).fill(null);
    const columns = Array(5).fill(null);
    return rows.map((item, ridx) => (
      <tr>
        {columns.map((item, cidx) => (
          <td>{`Row ${ridx + 1} - Column ${cidx + 1}`}</td>
        ))}
      </tr>
    ));
  }
```

Check out the demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/table-demo-fgd9i